# Load PreComputed Vectors Gensim

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec

I am using the Gensim Python package to learn a neural language model, and I know that you can provide a training corpus to learn the model. However, there already exist many precomputed word vectors available in text format (e.g. http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/). Is there some way to initialize a Gensim Word2Vec model that just makes use of some precomputed vectors, rather than having to learn the vectors from scratch?

Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can download pre-trained word vectors from here (get the file 'GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin'):
[word2vec](https://code.google.com/p/word2vec/)

Extract the file and then you can load it in python like:

```
model = gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin'), binary=True)

model.most_similar('dog')
```

EDIT (May 2017):
As the above code is now deprecated, this is how you'd load the vectors now:

```
model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin'), binary=True)
```

Answer (score 45):

The GloVe dump from the Stanford site is in a format that is little different from the word2vec format. You can convert the GloVe file into word2vec format using:

```
python -m gensim.scripts.glove2word2vec --input  glove.840B.300d.txt --output glove.840B.300d.w2vformat.txt
```

Comment: Worked on MacOS 10.13

Comment: As stated by @Chaitanya Shivade above loading.txt format form glove dataset gives the error in Gensim, so we can convert it into a format required by gensim like  w2vformat.txt or even glove.840B.300d.txt.word2vec

Comment: this is the right answer to load glove pre-trained models

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Gensim can load two binary formats, word2vec and fastText, and a generic plain text format which can be created by most word embedding tools. The generic plain text format looks like this (in this example 20000 is the size of the vocabulary and 100 is the length of vector)

```
20000 100
the 0.476841 -0.620207 -0.002157 0.359706 -0.591816 [98 more numbers...]
and 0.223408  0.231993 -0.231131 -0.900311 -0.225111 [98 more numbers..]
[19998 more lines...]
```

Chaitanya Shivade has explained in his answer here, how to use a script provided by Gensim to convert the Glove format (each line: word + vector) into the generic format.

Loading the different formats is easy, but it is also easy to get them mixed up:

```
import gensim
model_file = path/to/model/file
```

1) Loading binary word2vec

```
model = gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format(model_file)
```

2) Loading binary fastText

```
model = gensim.models.fasttext.FastText.load_fasttext_format(model_file)
```

3) Loading the generic plain text format (which has been introduced by word2vec)

```
model = gensim.models.keyedvectors.Word2VecKeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(model_file)
```

If you only plan to use the word embeddings and not to continue to train them in Gensim, you may want to use the KeyedVector class. This will reduce the amount of memory you need to load the vectors considerably ([detailed explanation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#why-use-keyedvectors-instead-of-a-full-model)).

The following will load the binary word2vec format as keyedvectors:

```
model = gensim.models.keyedvectors.Word2VecKeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(model_file, binary=True)
```